# Почему анимация отменяет transform?

Tags: css, css3

Привет. Использую для вертикального центрирования элемента свойства:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%)
```

Но когда к элементу применяется анимация:

```
animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

То свойство `transform` перестаёт работать. Почему?

Comment: Так а какая анимация у вас в `spin` прописана?

Comment: @Cheg `from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}` Я так понимаю, что использование rotate перезаписывает правило `translateY(-50%)`;

Comment: Так и напишите для `spin`: `from{transform:rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%);} to{transform:rotate(360deg)  translateY(-50%);}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
.child:hover {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:  translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чуть переделать надо. А то когда уводишь курсор - анимация скачет :)

Comment: Это уже вторая задача)

Comment: Не хотят твой ответ принимать никак :)